# docker windows 7 execute ipython tensorflow

Tags: docker, windows-7, ipython, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I recently installed docker on my windows 7 machine. I understand that docker is the way to go if I want to run tensorflow on windows machine. So  I have also downloaded tensorflow image using docker and I can run it from docker container.

Now I have bunch of ipython/.ipynb files. I don't know how I can execute them in docker. The ipython files import tensorflow.

I consider myself beginner. So the answers may be quite simple.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with docker, but I'd guess your docker file needs to mount the directory containing the `.ipynb` files, and install and start `jupyter notebook` so you can open them.

Comment: Additional info: `.ipynb` is the file extension for ipython notebooks as above comment suggests. [jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) is a server component that serves these notebooks to a (local) browser.